# windows phone 7 saving to camera roll - after cameracapturetask

Tags: windows-phone-7

I followed the many examples to do a [cameracapturetask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769543%28VS.92%29.aspx)

Now I would like to save the photo to my camera.  I can't seem to find that info on how to do so.  I've seen some stuff using the media library.  Is there a simple way using one of the tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the picture using MediaLibrary.SavePicture on the stream given to you as e.ChosenPhoto in the CameraCaptureTask_Completed event.

Comment: Right before I saw this answer, I found this post: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769549%28v=VS.92%29.aspx  Thank you!